# Searching value in string and replacing it with double quotes in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, string

1. Adds a new field Match_PINCODE
2. Searches for a 6digit number in a string from Address field like "aaaaa,dsjfhdjfhd768543"
3. set "Match_PINCODE" field with the 6digit row by row.
4. Replaces 6digit number with ""

The 3 steps take almost less than a minute but calculatefield is taking a lot of time.Does anyone have better approach? so that i can fetch 6 digit number from one field update it into another field and finally replace 6 digit number with doublequotes.

```
import arcpy,os,re
import arcgisscripting

ints = []
cnt=0

gp=arcgisscripting.create()
gp.toolbox="management"
fc=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fc_fld=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)


try:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Adding Field ")

    gp.addfield(fc, "Match_PINCODE", "TEXT", "#","#",10, "#","NULLABLE","#", "#")

except:
  print "Error occured while adding Fields"
  print gp.GetMessages(2)

try:
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc,"","",fc_fld)
    for row in rows:
          cnt=cnt+1
          value=row.getValue(fc_fld)
          p=re.findall(r'\d{6}\b',value)

          for s in p:
            ints.append(int(s))
            finalval=int(int(s))
            if str(finalval) <> "":
                whereclause=fc_fld + " LIKE " + "'" +"%" + str(finalval) + "%"+"'"
                cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc,whereclause)
                row = cursor.next()
                while row:
                    row.setValue('Match_PINCODE', str(finalval))
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
                    row = cursor.next()

            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc,"NEW_SELECTION",whereclause)

            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,fc_fld,'!'+fc_fld+'!.replace('+"'"+str(finalval)+"'"+',"")',"PYTHON_9.3")

            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
            arcpy.AddMessage("Row Count:" + str(cnt))

except:
  print "Error"
```

Comment: Consider using arcpy.da search and update cursors, they're much faster. How many rows are seleced by the whereclause in the layer? It might be better to use a 2nd update cursor. I note that you're not deleting your cursors which is a no-no for non da cursors, if you choose to stick with them you need to del cursor immediately after the updates are finished.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What version of ArcGIS are you using?  Tagging 3 (possibly quite different) versions isn't very helpful to potential answerers

Comment: For someone new to the site asking ArcPy questions I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach that uses an [Update Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) and a regular expression. You will notice significant performance enhancements with the data access Update Cursor. The regular expression is used to find a series of 6 digits in a search string. It is handy to go to the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) to test regular expressions.

```
import arcpy, re

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\feature_class'

AddField_management (fc, "Match_PINCODE", "TEXT")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("Address", "Match_PINCODE")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #find exactly 6 of any digit and replace with double quotes
        row[1] = row[0].replace(re.findall(r'\d{6}', row[0])[0], '""') 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```